# How to find out the maximum number of contacts that the SIM card phonebook can hold?

Tags: contacts, storage, sim-card

I have searched and searched to find out how many contacts my SIM card can hold, but no apps are giving me the answer. Many sites recommended checking the size of SIM card which is printed on it. In my case it's a 64K card, but many sites say that it should support "around 250 contacts" or "usually 500 contacts".

Where or how can I get an authoritative answer?

Answer (score 2):

[European Telecommunications Standards Institute (ETSI)](http://www.etsi.org/technologies-clusters/technologies/smart-cards/sim) lays down standards for SIM

From 3GPP TS 21.111 version 8.0.1 Release 8 pertaining to 3G

> 10.2.6 Number of entries : The specification shall support storage of at least 500 entries.

This does not mention the SIM storage size in relation to the number of entries

I was hoping to find a  correlation between size and entries and this is the only thing I could find.